# How to add variable exponent in my model in Gurobi while solving an optimization problem?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

As addGenConstrPow accepts a constant exponent, it does not accept k, which is an iterator variable. Is there an alternative way of doing it?

Following is the code snippet,

```
myAuxVar= m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="myAuxVar")
m.addConstr(myAuxVar==Lambda * w)
powconstr1=m.addGenConstrPow(myAuxVar, v, k, "pow2", "FuncPieces=1000")
```

where k is an iterator variable

I receive the following error message-
Encountered an attribute error

Thanks

Comment: Please update with the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Anyhow, I missed your comment. The error is "Encountered an attribute error", whenever I put k in the addGenConstrPow. It starts working fine if I put a constant term in place of k.